# Pytorch Device-Side Assert on Backward()

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I have the following error when training a graph neural network using pytorch and pytorch geometric:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s3092593/as-graph/slurm/../train.py", line 204, in <module>
    train(config)
  File "/home/s3092593/as-graph/slurm/../train.py", line 100, in train
    train_loss, train_runtime, train_accuracy, train_dist = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, runtime_evaluator, accuracy_evaluator,
  File "/home/s3092593/as-graph/deeper_gnn/train.py", line 76, in train
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
  File "/data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 488, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 197, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

I ran the code with `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`. The error happens after many batches (but the exact number changes from run to run)
When it happens, it also prints many asserts (I didn't include all of them as there are over 100):

```
...
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [57,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [58,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [59,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [60,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [61,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [62,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScatterGatherKernel.cu:144: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [63,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
...
```

The C++ stack trace (by setting `TORCH_SHOW_CPP_STACKTRACES=1`) is:

```
Exception raised from c10_cuda_check_implementation at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525541990/work/c10/cuda/CUDAException.cpp:31 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x57 (0x2aab3d352457 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::string const&) + 0x64 (0x2aab3d31c3ec in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: c10::cuda::c10_cuda_check_implementation(std::string const&, std::string const&, int, bool) + 0xb4 (0x2aab0b65c044 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #3: void at::native::gpu_reduce_kernel<float, float, 4, at::native::func_wrapper_t<float, __nv_hdl_wrapper_t<false, true, __nv_dl_tag<void (at::native::sum_functor<float, float, float>::*)(at::TensorIterator&), &at::native::sum_functor<float, float, float>::operator(), 1u>, float (float, float)> >, double>(at::TensorIterator&, at::native::func_wrapper_t<float, __nv_hdl_wrapper_t<false, true, __nv_dl_tag<void (at::native::sum_functor<float, float, float>::*)(at::TensorIterator&), &at::native::sum_functor<float, float, float>::operator(), 1u>, float (float, float)> > const&, double, at::native::AccumulationBuffer*, long) + 0x11e5 (0x2aab0d73b545 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x20b6755 (0x2aab0d729755 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so)
frame #5: at::native::structured_sum_out::impl(at::Tensor const&, c10::OptionalArrayRef<long>, bool, c10::optional<c10::ScalarType>, at::Tensor const&) + 0xa6 (0x2aaaff8a0636 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #6: <unknown function> + 0x2af36d3 (0x2aab0e1666d3 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so)
frame #7: <unknown function> + 0x2af376f (0x2aab0e16676f in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so)
frame #8: at::_ops::sum_dim_IntList::redispatch(c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&, c10::OptionalArrayRef<long>, bool, c10::optional<c10::ScalarType>) + 0x8a (0x2aab000b710a in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x3a8513a (0x2aab0192113a in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #10: <unknown function> + 0x3a85666 (0x2aab01921666 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #11: at::_ops::sum_dim_IntList::call(at::Tensor const&, c10::OptionalArrayRef<long>, bool, c10::optional<c10::ScalarType>) + 0x193 (0x2aab00111bb3 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #12: <unknown function> + 0x4395c96 (0x2aab02231c96 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #13: torch::autograd::Engine::evaluate_function(std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::GraphTask>&, torch::autograd::Node*, torch::autograd::InputBuffer&, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&) + 0x800 (0x2aab02237a40 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #14: torch::autograd::Engine::thread_main(std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::GraphTask> const&) + 0x698 (0x2aab022393e8 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #15: torch::autograd::Engine::thread_init(int, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&, bool) + 0x8b (0x2aab0223084b in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #16: torch::autograd::python::PythonEngine::thread_init(int, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&, bool) + 0x5c (0x2aaaf50bd46c in /data1/s3092593/thesis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #17: <unknown function> + 0xdbbf4 (0x2aaac30a4bf4 in /data1/s3092593/thesis/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6)
frame #18: <unknown function> + 0x7ea5 (0x2aaaaacd6ea5 in /lib64/libpthread.so.0)
frame #19: clone + 0x6d (0x2aaaab6f2b0d in /lib64/libc.so.6)
```

However, I cannot find the source of the error. I checked the sizes of the outputs and the targets. The error occurs in different times (one time after 100 batches, one time after 250 batches). When using CPU instead of GPU, the error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

My loss function was returning a big number, more than 9 digits. I simply divided it by 10000000 to scale it down and it solved the problem for me.

Apparently, some variable in pytorch can't handle such large values.